# What is the most efficient way to bring large amount of data from the database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

I have a stored proc that returns 7 data tables from a SQL Server in its resultset.  It uses about 400 MB of bandwidth to bring the data to the client for processing.

The code to bring the data back is fairly simple:

```
private DataSet CreateDataSet(SqlCommand command)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

    da.Fill(dataSet);
    da.Dispose();

    return dataSet;
}
```

The problem is that on the database this sproc is causing a pretty large wait of type ASYNC_NETWORK_IO, which, the documentation says, means that the client can't keep up with the database.

My question is how can I bring this data to the client in a faster manner that eliminates or reduces the ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait on the server?

Some facts:

- The database server is on the same box as the application, thus the connection type is Shared Memory, not TCP.
- The data tables are dependent on each other, thus breaking out the data tables into separate stored procs is not an option.

Comment: Are you really going to try and process 400MB at a time? Do you need to load it all at once.. ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Unfortunately yes.  No way around it.

Comment: What kind of processing are you doing on the client that you can't do on the server?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman The type of processing being done is much faster in C# than SQL. This has been proven out.

Comment: I doubt much can be done to speed things up because the issue is just the amount of data getting pumped over your network. Look into using SQL windowing functions to return n-records at a time to the client (which is what #Simon is implying, I think), or invest in better hardware ($$$).

Comment: Is this something that can be ported to SQL Server using the CLR layer?

Comment: Comparing C# and SQL performance is an invalid comparison; one must compare SQL to Download + c# + Upload, and clearly in your environment the network latencies are such as to make performing in SQL preferable.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens OP said Shared Memory.  Client cannot keep up with database is not a latency problem.

Comment: @Blam: Technically you are correct; I misspoke. But my point is that only the round-trip performance time is a fair or meaningful comparison to the SQL time.

Comment: So the tables are dependent.  Do you really need ALL the data in .NET at one time to do what you need.  What is the nature or the analysis?  Even if you need all the data at once then why do you need it in a DataSet?

Comment: Just thinking out of the box, is it feasible to dump the dataset to an SQL text file on the server, compress it to a zip and then send it to the client?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens But the stated problem is not time.  The stated problem is ASYNC_NETWORK_IO.  It does not matter how fast I am running as long as I am running faster than the bear.

Comment: Nothing is going to be faster than processing that much data on the machine where it originates. If for no other reason than you don't have the transfer time of the network. The OP has yet to say if this could be converted to CLR over SQL. And if it can't then, move the client application to the server that does this process. If all of your clients perform this process, it is time to look at what you are doing and why.

Comment: This looks like an X - Y Problem. **What** processing is being done that is so much faster in C# than SQL? **Why** are we sure that C# is so much faster (especially given the common error of solving SQL problems with cursors)?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman What part of "The database server is on the same box as the application, thus the connection type is Shared Memory" is not clear?

Comment: @Blam, I missed that...

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The performance of C# + download is greatly superior to a SQL solution.  The reason I know is that I rewrote a SQL only solution (which was optimized to death over the years) as C# app.  And the performance was improved by a factor of nearly a 100 (of workloads being processed).  Even now with the ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait, the performance of the application is great.  I am just trying to minimize its impact on the database server.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman It is theoretically possible to port the app (it's a windows service) to SQL Server CLR sprocs, but I don't really think it's a good idea because the service does a lot of other things as well that would not be well suited to running under SQL Server.

Comment: @Blam Unfortunately I do need all information.  The primary nature of the application is scheduling via a massive amount of complex rules (thus you have to bring all that data down). As far as why does it need to be in a DataSet...it doesn't - just happens to be a convenient way to bring all needed data in one shot.  What alternative do you suggest?

Comment: A DataTable is heavy.  Custom classes or struts in collections filled via DataReader is an option.

Comment: @AngryHacker, is there any of the data that can be cached locally so you don't have to pull the entire dataset with every run? From what you said to Blam, it would lead me to think that at least some of it can be. How often do the rules change?